# Is there an MKS unit system in which electric and magnetic fields have the same measurement unit?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, units, si-units

I'd like to know if there's an MKS unit system in which electric and magnetic fields have the same measurement unit. I couldn't find anything like that on the internet. Does that system exist? Do people use it? What is it called?

Comment: You could invent a unit system that is to MKS what the Gaussian EM units are to CGS - i.e. use the exact same derivational procedure but with m, kg, and s replacing cm, g, and s respectively. It is not SI, of course, but it fits your definition. E.g. the "MKS Gaussian" units would have a unit of charge where that two charges 1 m apart produce 1 N of force instead of 1 cm apart making 1 dyn of force. For "MKS HLU", produce $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ N of force.

Comment: Not sure how many floors go with 14.2 m either.  Now if you give it to me in feet, I've got it since I know there are 8-10 ft per floor. Not that science should convert to feet, only that your argument both for "civilized" and against "natural" are somewhat nonsensical. If people used the units more, then they'd have a better sense for them (presumably at the expense of what they use now, whatever that may be). Grace Hopper, for example, used to handout nanosecond-length pieces of wire so that students would build exactly that intuition. There's a permanent display of one at the USNA.

Comment: @Brick You have a point. Forgive my childishness.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I know that. I am asking if such a system has been already done/used by someone else, and if it has a name.

Comment: Two votes down? Why is that? Alright guys.. I must say I am a bit surprised. I'll edit and keep only the question per say. I won't kid anymore around here. I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units). Very simply, all dimensional conversions are set equal to 1: 
$$c=\hbar=\epsilon_0=\mu_0=1 , $$
and so forth. It is commonly used in particle physics.